# Cannot Stub Function Returning Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, sinon, stub

I was trying to stub an arrow function `removeUserEntry`, but when executing `acctRmRouter` in the test, my stub seems being ignored. I have to explicitly stub the `UserModel`'s `deleteOne` method to get the test successfully, I am wondering why the ignorance happens, thank you

**acctRoute.js**

```js
const removeUserEntry = (username) => {
    const condition = {username: username};

    return UserModel.deleteOne(condition)
       .then((res) => {
           if (res.n < 1) {
               throw new Error('User not exists');
           }
           return true;
       }, (err) => {throw err})
       .catch(err => err);
};

const acctRmRouter = function(httpReq, httpRes, next) {
    if (!argValidate(httpReq.body, 'string')) {
        httpRes.locals = {api: { success: false }};
        // return to avoid running downwards
        return next(new Error('bad argument'));
    }

    // perform DB rm user
    return removeUserEntry(httpReq.body).then((res) => {
        if (res === true) {
            httpRes.locals = {api: { success: true }};
            next();
        } else {
            httpRes.locals = {api: { success: false }}
            next(res);
        }
    });
};
```

**acctRoute.spec.js**

```js
it('should remove user handler pass success request', async () => {
    shouldDbReset = false;
    const mockRequestURL = "/api/account/rm-user";
    const mockRequest = httpMocks.createRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: mockRequestURL,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
        body: 'validRmUser',
    });
    const mockResponse = httpMocks.createResponse();
    const spyNext = sinon.spy();
    const stubRemoveUserEntry = sinon.stub(accountRouterHelper, 'removeUserEntry'); 

    stubRemoveUserEntry.callsFake(function(){
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }); // Expecting this function to be stubbed, and always return true

    await accountRouterHelper.acctRmRouter(mockRequest, mockResponse, spyNext); 
    /* But when running the function, it returns error object with "User not exists" 
    which is not what intended */

    const firstCallArgs = spyNext.getCall(0).args[0];

    expect(spyNext.called).to.be.true;
    console.log(`firstCallArgs: ${firstCallArgs}`)
    expect(firstCallArgs instanceof Error).to.be.false;
    expect(spyNext.args[0].length).to.equal(0);
    expect(mockResponse.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    expect(mockResponse.locals.api.success).to.be.true;

    stubRemoveUserEntry.resetHistory();
    stubRemoveUserEntry.restore();
});
```

---

The following indeed stubbed successfully with similar pattern to `removeUserEntry`.

**acctRoute.js**

```
const createUserEntry = (userData) => {
    const updatedUserData = filterInput(userData);
    const userDoc = new UserModel(updatedUserData);
    return userDoc.save()
    .then((userObj) => userObj._doc
    ,(err) => { throw err;})
    .catch(err => err);
};

const acctCreateRouter = function (httpReq, httpRes, next) {
// do something in mongodb
return createUserEntry(userCondition)
   .then((response) => {
            if (!(response instanceof Error)) {
                httpRes.locals = {api: { success: true}};
                next();
            } else {
                httpRes.locals = {api: { success: false}};
                next(response);
            }
        }, (err) => {
            httpRes.locals = {api: { success: false}};
            next(err);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            httpRes.locals = {api: { success: false}};
            next(err);
        });     
};

const acctOutputRouter = function(req, res, next) {
    if (res.locals) {
        res.send(res.locals.api);
    } else {next()}
};
```

**acctRoute.spec.js**

```
it("should return and save the success result to response locals for next route", () => {
        shouldDbReset = false;
        const mockResponse = httpMocks.createResponse();
        const stubCreateUserEntry = sinon.stub(accountRouterHelper, 'createUserEntry');
        const mockNext = sinon.spy();

        stubCreateUserEntry.callsFake(function(){
            return Promise.resolve();
        }); // Unlike removeUserEntry, stubbing neatly with desired output
        return accountRouterHelper.acctCreateRouter(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext)
        .then(() => {
            expect(mockNext.called).to.be.true;
            expect(mockResponse.locals.api.success).to.be.true;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            mockNext.resetHistory();
            stubCreateUserEntry.restore();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

`sinon.stub(accountRouterHelper, 'removeUserEntry')` replaces the module export.

`acctRmRouter()` is not calling the module export, it is calling `removeUserEntry()` directly so stubbing the module export does nothing.

**Solution**

Refactor `acctRmRouter()` to call the module export for `removeUserEntry()`.

**ES6**

```
// import module into itself
import * as self from './acctRoute';

...

const acctRmRouter = function(httpReq, httpRes, next) {

    ...

    // call the function using the module
    return self.removeUserEntry(httpReq.body).then((res) => {

    ...
```

**Node.js module**

```
...

const acctRmRouter = function(httpReq, httpRes, next) {

  ...

  // call the function using module.exports
  return module.exports.removeUserEntry(httpReq.body).then((res) => {

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for not being presented good enough, actually there is another similar pattern `createUserEntry` functions which can be stubbed neatly (referring to the updated code), I am wondering why the `removeUserEntry` is not working under the same pattern

Comment: @user2361494 can you post the code for `acctOutputRouter()`?  I would need to see that before I could respond

Comment: `accountRouterHelper.acctOutputRouter()` does not appear to call `createUserEntry()` so the stub is never used in that test.  The test should still pass if the stub is removed completely

Comment: My apology...dumb for me, I provide another irrelevant test, I have updated the right test case for `createUserEntry`

Comment: @user2361494 are `acctCreateRouter()` and `createUserEntry()` both defined in `acctRoute.js`?  Can you share the code for `createUserEntry()`?

Comment: Yes, basically I put all the route related stuffs in `acctRoute.js` for better management. Sure, I have further updated the source. Once again thanks for the kind help

Comment: Hmm...stubbing `createUserEntry()` shouldn't work since `acctCreateRouter()` appears to call it directly from within the same file so if the stub really does get called instead of the real function in the test then there must be something about your codebase or environment that I can't see from the code snippets provided

Comment: As you said Brian, directly calling `removeUserEntry` is the cause of the failure of the stub, using `this.removeUserEntry` solves the stubbing problem, as now `this` becomes the calling object, which can then be successfully stubbed